# Using range and dictionary in Python's Bellman-Ford implementation

Tags: python, graph

The Bellman-Ford algorithm looks like this

```
initialize-single-source(G,s)
for i = 1 to |G.V| - 1
   for each edge (u,v) in G.E
      call Relax(u,v,w)

and so on
```

This psuedocode index begins with 1, not zero.

Here is how I called the edge. I use dictionary for edge and vertex.

```
    for i in range((len(self.V.keys()))-1):
        for vertex in self.V.keys():
            for edge in self.V[vertex]:
```

Q1: We should begin with index zero, right?

Q2: Should we still minus 1 from the length of G.V ?

Thanks.

Comment: Advice: use `self.V.items()` to iterate a dictionary (Better performance if you access value in loop)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you already give [this super website](http://www.google.de/search?q=bellman%20fords%20python) a try? Sometimes answers can be found there...

Comment: Thanks gecco. Yeah. I probably skipped the top returned website. Thanks.

Comment: I just noticed that the website used a different API.  It uses "for i in range(len(graph)-1)", and then look at each vertex, and each edge. Does this affect how I use the range regarding my question Thanks.

Comment: Gecco, Thanks. I misread something. Sorry for confusing you. :))

Answer (score 3):

> Q1: We should begin with index zero, right?

Not necessarily; you could also iterate over `xrange(1, len(self.V))`. Starting from zero is idiomatic, though.

> Q2: Should we still minus 1 from the length of G.V?

If you start counting from zero, yes. The `-1` is part of the algorithm specification.

Extra advice: rewrite your snippet as

```
for i in xrange(len(self.V) - 1):
    for vertex in self.V.iterkeys():
        for edge in self.V[vertex]:
```

to prevent building a list of keys (twice).

Comment: Why is it valid to begin with range(1) instead of range(0)? I am more of a C++ guy. According to doc, range begins with 0 if the first argument is omitted. We can omitted range(0) because that doesn't help in the algorithm?  Thanks.

Comment: @user963889: because the B-F algorithm doesn't actually care about the indices, only the number of times the inner loop executes.